# How obtain mass-weighted coordinates used to plot intrinsic reaction coordinates

Tags: computational-chemistry

I have obtained the energies from an IRC calculation. Usually these are plotted in papers vs the mass weighted coordinates; often something like this is labeled on the x axis: $Å \times \sqrt{\mbox{amu}}$.

How do I obtain these coordinates?

### Possible solution

With some reading, I came up with a possible solution. Apparently the IRC step size (used in Molcas calculations) are in units of Bohr in normalized mass-weighted coordinates. So all I need to do is to do the following

- Set the TS data point to 0
- Multiply the step number (TS is "step 0") with the step size
- Multiply the above with the Borh-to-Ångström conversion factor (0.529177249)
- The direction to reactant should be negative
- The direction to product should be positive

Comment: Could you include a paper where they do that as an example?

Comment: See Fig. 2 in West et al: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jpca.5b03402

Comment: You seem to have overlooked the contribution of the correction step (during the iterations of the IRC method) to the mass-weighted coordinates.